# Three.js - Change Material on Runtime

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, three.js

I have some .js files exported from Blender and load them with `THREE.JSONLoader();`

my callback:

```
var callback   = function( geometry ) { createMesh(geometry);
```

my loading:

```
loader.load( "Models/sculp.js", callback );
```

my create method:

```
function createMesh(geometry){

    inArr[id] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xbbbbbb} ) );
    inArr[id].scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
    scene.add( inArr[id] );
    id++;
}
```

Now I want to change my material on runtime by using my keyboard (changes color and opacity).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As you create a new material for each mesh I assume you only want to change the color of one mesh and not of all in the `inArr` array, and you probably need some sort of select for that. But changing the color of the material alone is quite easy:

```
var onKeyDown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 67) { // when 'c' is pressed
    object.material.color.setHex(0xff0000); // there is also setHSV and setRGB
  }
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false);
```

`object` is the mesh you want to change. Key codes can be found here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: thanks a lot. It works fine now I tryed it with cube and sphere some days before and i used: `THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy( obj, function ( geo ) { geo.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x900000 } ); } );`but now i only can use `obj.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( .. );`