# Create human body (Editable/Updateable) using A-Frame like three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I want to create a human body using a frame where i can update the model, cloths, and other measurement. In  three.js i tried and its working there but i don't know how to do that thing in A Frame ?

Refer link oh three.js Model : [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_human)

Comment: In A-Frame, you wrap three.js code in components: https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/component.html

Comment: So can we update Collada (.dae) file components also ?

Comment: Yeah, just traverse the object3d once the collada meshes are loaded in

Comment: yes traverse() will working fine with components. But when i use second time on onclick event my changed was not affected in model. Here is Example text file. [CODE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4zkSgVE4wsANVkyN2IxNUlsQnc)

Comment: components are statically registered just once before the scene, they aren't meant to be called like functions. the code you have is *registering* a component, not invoking its code. you need to add event handling within a component.

Comment: how we can use that component with event handling ?  So we can click the button and update the properties of collada model.

Comment: write an event listener (`el.addEventListener('click', function () { // ... Do stuff })`)

Comment: When i used this with click event its give model is undefined. Here is Code : `AFRAME.registerComponent('model-overrider', {
   init: function() { // update also i used
     this.el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       var model = e.detail.model;
    alert("1."+model)
    model.traverse(function(o) {
     alert("2."+o)
      if (o instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
   alert("3."+o.material);
   o.material.color = new THREE.color("red");
  
         }
       });
     });
   }
 });`   Here alert(1) is giving undefined value. So traverse() not work.

Comment: Where'd you get `e.detail.model` from? You can `console.log(e.detail)`. Get `e.detail.el`. Then `el.getObject3D('mesh');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Collada (.dae ) file code from A-Frame or JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585192/update-collada-dae-file-code-from-a-frame-or-js)

Comment: Thank You for your help @ngokevin. Now i did it using onclick event. Now i am able to change material and geometry of dae on onclick action. I am not using AFRAME.registerComponent or el.addEventListener. Thank you so much.