# Can three.js editor export a JS script?

Tags: three.js, editor

I created some educational HTML content in which I load several HTML files with three.js models through their respective iframes.

Maybe is not optimal but this way I managed to create individual orbit controls and dat.gui menus for each model satisfactorily.

Since the models are getting more complex, I would appreciate the help of the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/), but I prefer to keep control over the model code so I can have all gathered in one file and I can change easily sizes, colors, dat-gui menus, etc. Moreover I can avoid to load through the iframe a HTML file that in turn has to load a model in any other format (json, dae, gltf, obj, etc.). I think that is quite cumbersome.

Is it possible then to export the script and paste it in the HTML file?

EDIT: Before asking this question I did not find an answer, but there was. There is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76373385/how-export-javascript-from-the-threejs-editor) in which a similar question was asked and the answers was a rotund no. Since three.js is a JS library, I though it was possible to get the raw code. I find it easier to modify it than to learn how to code to change the parameters of any other file type.